# FBSDKAppInviteDialog, restarting the app when leaving

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2

I'm inviting friends to use the application through the FBSDKAppInviteDialog provided by the Facebook SDK.

```
let inviteDialog:FBSDKAppInviteDialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
    if(inviteDialog.canShow()){
        let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
        content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "xxxxxxxx")
        content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "xxx")
        inviteDialog.delegate = self
        inviteDialog.fromViewController = self
        inviteDialog.content = content
        inviteDialog.show()
    }
```

And the delegate methods:

```
extension InviteFriendsEmailViewController: FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate{
func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
}
func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
}}
```

Everything is working properly except that when the invitations are sent (successfully), I'm redirected at the initial UIViewController of my storyboard.. I don't know why. Like if the application was restarting.

Is there someone that could help me?

Thank you by advance ! 
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that when you are leaving the FBSDKAppInviteDialog, you're entering the AppDelegate function :

```
 func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
```

And in this function I was parsing some dynamic links and opening some other UIViewControllers !

Hope this will help someone ^^

Bye !